# VS Code: Use the list of multi-root workspace folders during dev container build

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, vscode-devcontainer, devcontainer

I have a `~/projects/` directory with a bunch of cloned Git repos in it. I like to select subsets of these and save them as VS Code [multi-root workspaces](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces) as `~/projects/*.code-workspace`.

I also use a dev container, configured with `~/projects/.devcontainer.json` so that all the workspaces find it automatically.

When I build a dev container, I would love to be able to run some initialization logic with the input being **the list of folders in the open workspace.**

I can use `${containerWorkspaceFolder}` in [`.devcontainer.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/devcontainerjson-reference), but this gives me `~/projects`, not the exact `.code-workspace` file, and there are multiple `.code-workspace` files in the directory. If I could get the path of the current .code-workspace file, I could parse the json and get the folder list, but it seems I can only get the parent folder.

I tried setting `terminal.integrated.env.linux` in `foo.code-workspace` to set a per-workspace environment variable `CODE_WORKSPACE_FILE=~/projects/foo.code-workspace`, but it isn't visible to the devcontainer build, only in integrated terminals I open after the workspace is already open in the container.

I see that there is a [`workspace.workspaceFolders()`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#workspace) method in the vscode extension API. I don't want to write an extension just to expose that value to the devcontainers system, but maybe that's the only way currently.

Any other ideas?

Comment: `devcontainer.json` does not have a mechanism to call VSC command so an extension will not help you

Comment: I would absolutely love to be able to load a workspace config file during the dev container build. That'd be so awesome!

Answer (score 0):

It isn't exactly what you asked for, but you can use code-workspace files in a devcontainer if you mount your source code in devcontainer.json. You can use the `mounts` property in devcontainer.json (https://containers.dev/implementors/json_reference/).

First, add the following to your devcontainer.json file:

```
"mounts": [
  {"source":"~/projects","/projects","type":"bind"},
],
```

Second move your .devcontainer folder to an empty directory. For example, you could make a folder named for the container template or your project in home directory, something like `~/nodejs-postgres`. Copy your *.code-workspace files into the .devcontainer folder. You should have the following folder structure:

```
- ~/nodejs-postgres
  - .devcontainer
    - devcontainer.json
    - project1.code-workspace
    - project2.code-workspace
    - ...
```

Next, edit the code-workspace files so the paths use `/projects` instead of `~/projects`.

Finally open `~/nodejs-postgres` in a devcontainer. After the container is built and ready to use, you should have a code window with just the devcontainer folder open. Your entire projects folder is mounted in the container, but the folders aren't open in vscode.

At this point, you can use the Add Folder to Workspace command to add a folder to the current workspace in the devcontainer or you can open one of your code-workspace files in an editor and click the `Open Workspace` button that comes up. After clicking the button, it will open the mounted project folders in the container.